# Omnet++: getting .ned file after simulations has ended

Tags: simulation, simulator, omnet++

When my simulation, using Omnet++, starts, there is a .ned file describing the initial scenario (in my case it shows a certain type of a network configuration). During the simulation this scenario changes, come times it changes very much. Is there a way to get a .ned file describing the final scenario after the simulation has ended? So that I can analyze it with a script...
thnaks

Answer (score 0):

Not the NED file, because that describes the initial network structure in an abstract way (i.e. it can contain vectors, loops, conditional statements etc.)

What you need is a simple dump of all or selected objects. You should use the 'snapshot feature' for this. It produces a nicely formatted XML output. You can read more about it in the manual:

http://www.omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec299